# What practices would keep ruling aristocrats young?

Tags: politics, law, feudalism

This world has a society with fairly modern technology (late 20th century or later) with a natural, reasonably healthy life span of 70+ years for people barring accidents, homicides, suicides, or a rare deadly pandemic. There is no magic and no currently impossible technology.

In such a society, what kind of practices, other than a formal arbitrary retirement age, might keep the leaders of a nation, or sub-component of a nation, in a feudal, hereditary system made up mostly of young adults (say, typically in their mid-20s to early 50s with a median or mean somewhere in the middle of that range) at both the highest level of the reigning king and at each level below that down to the humblest hereditary lord with a low ranking and small fiefdom.

In other words, would practices or elements of the system could cause the older generation to relinquish their positions of authority before they die of natural causes or the infirmities of old age?

Comment: Asking for an open ended list to help you brainstorm and generate ideas is not prohibited on this site. Can you try asking for something more specific? For instance, come up with an idea on your own and ask us for help with the specific difficulties you encounter getting it to fit into your world.

Comment: Loosely related : [What political advantages a kingdom can have when power is passed on as early as possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192401/what-political-advantages-if-any-a-kingdom-can-have-when-power-is-passed-on-to). Otherwise, I agree that attacking the whole noble caste in a society we don't know anything about is a bit too broad of a swipe. Can we know what kind of society/culture you're making or are inspired from?

Answer (score 4):

**Frame challenge - not plausible**

1. Assuming that this is a "real" feudal system rather than relatively powerless figureheads in a democracy (eg Great Britain) then they can be equated to dictators.  Ex-dictators have *really* low life expectancy, which is why they will do almost anything to hang onto power.  So one of the absolute requirements in order to get a feudal leader to retire is an assurance that "retirement" won't be to a plot of ground six foot by three or imprisonment for actions undertaken during their reign.  While extremely rare leaders may trust their successor to honour a promise to let them retire safely, this would normally require legislation of the kind that is against the spirit of this question's terms.
2. Many high-level leaders (and high-performing people in all careers) get bored in retirement.  All their skills and knowledge are focused on knowing the right people and how to interact with (manipulate) them to achieve the outcomes they want, a body of experience they have built up over many years.  Why would they voluntarily give that up just to let some relatively inexperienced newcomer take over, especially in the middle of the critical ongoing crisis?  Given that there is *always* a new crisis, this becomes a never-ending justification for keeping on going.  Again, the way to force handover is with legislation directly or indirectly limiting term length, which is exactly what you don't want.  Further, unless the legislation is watertight then it is likely that the ex-leader will keep running things from behind the scenes by ensuring their successor is someone they can manipulate - "for their own good" if they are benevolent.
3. War leaders no longer lead from the front.  Back in the old days it was important to see the banner of the king in the front ranks.  Modern weapons systems make that idea idiotic today - in order to get the big picture of what is happening and make good decisions (not to mention avoiding sniper bullets), senior commanders need to be secure behind the rest of their soldiers.  Younger minds may be flexible and faster, but the strategic level at which a ruler is making decisions is all about "war is an extension of politics", where political acumen is vital.  (So long as they listen to the advice of their professional soldiers re what is possible and the consequences of a given course of action.)  Of course, if the army is organised on feudal lines rather than being led by a professional corps of officers then there is benefit to the low-ranking feudal lords being young enough to fight, but such an organisation won't last long against a modern professional army.

TL;DR the objective cannot be achieved without highly prescriptive legislation.  The legislation needs to protect the ex-rulers from post-rule retribution and prevent them from trying to puppet-master the current generation of young rulers.

Answer (score 3):

**Competitive aristocracy**

Your nobility may be hereditary, and that's Ok, but your monarchy is not. A monarch is selected from a pool of eligible nobles via complex trials - and his (or her) reign has term limits.

Trials may include everything that you want from a young monarch - a "spelling bee" contest or jousting - just make sure that young people would have an edge in the competition.

P.S. This can not be an absolute monarchy - it has to be a constitutional one. However, the king or queen can have high level of power, similar to US president, rather than ceremonial power similar to European monarchs.

Answer (score 2):

I think there would be two elements to this. First, for some reason most societies in your world have a strongly ageist culture, where anyone older than early-mid fifties, no matter how capable and popular, would be seen as over the hill and not suitable for holding any position of responsibility. This may be because the dominant religion of your world declares this to always be true. Or perhaps in your world diseases that don't kill the sufferer but lead to cognitive decline are much more common after early fifties.

The second element would be, your aristocracy is in an insecure position. There are many calls for reform, either complete abolition of hereditary feudalism or at least reducing its power. The aristocratic elite must constantly project an image of being strong and capable, which in your world means being in a certain age bracket. So there is pressure on older feudal lords to abdicate in favor of the younger heir to ensure the rule of their noble family doesn't collapse altogether.

Answer (score 1):

**Ultimogeniture,** in which the *youngest* heir inherits the position upon the death of the noble, has historically been pretty unusual here on Earth, but it should serve your purpose of keeping the ruling aristocracy young well-enough.

Answer (score 0):

Many people do not want to give up power. Just look at the difficulty in getting older people to give up the keys to their car. The only way is to make the "retirement" more attractive than clinging to power.

One way would be to make ruling be an unpaid position. All benefits come after retirement. In retirement, they get the parades, the limo rides, the special deals, and all "gifts" while ruling can only be used in retirement.